# Why are quaternions more popular than tessarines despite being non-commutative?

Tags: mathematics, complex-analysis, algebra, numbers, quaternions

Is this simply because of marketing, hype, etc?

The bicomplex numbers (**especially** tessarines) look just great being commutative and all.

[image]

[image]

Images source:https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.527.356&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Quaternions are useful. In particular for representation of rotations of 3-space.

Comment: An interesting study: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1511/1511.06917.pdf

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker thanks, another study shows a huge advantage of tessarines over all other algebras and total uselessness of quaternions: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.527.356&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thanks. Besides, I have written, some years ago an answer on MathStackExchange giving as well different correspondances of bi-complex numbers, quaternions, etc. with **matrices** [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1917093)

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker look at this my answer also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187160/what-is-the-difference-between-quaternions-and-bicomplex-numbers/4024581#4024581 It shows advantages of bicomplex numbers over quaternions, but tessarines are even better in that its $j^2=1$ coincides with hyperbolic numbers, and we do not need to add another unity. So, we have i, j, ij, adding only complex unity and hyperbolic unity to reals. Also, they have alternating signs of squares of unities, so that we can make 16-dimentioned tessarines, which are still commutative and associative.

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker and this alternating pattern simplifies processing with DSPs as highlighted in the link, and one can easy write down the matrix form for any dimension, without remembering patterns.

Comment: Maybe, it is a little exaggerate to say such definitive things like "a huge advantage of tessarines over all other algebras and total uselessness of quaternions"...

Comment: @Anixx If a study shows the 'total uselessness' of quaternions, then that study is clearly flawed, as illustrated by the many uses of quaternions.

Comment: I've just asked [Are bicomplex numbers including tessarines ever used in spaceflight as an alternative to quaternions?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50123/12102)

Comment: @uhooh quaternions are like coordinates or rotations on the sphere. Bicomplex numbers are numbers

Comment: Quaternions are like vectors

Comment: @Solomon slow i agree with you. My only point, it is not numbers like. For instance, a computer algebra system needs separate functions for quaternions, like for matrices, whereas tessarines, hyperbolic numbes and dual numbers can be added by adding a constant ans a few rules

Comment: Matrices are also not numbers, even though they are very well useful

Comment: Deleting my previous comment and saying it differently: Being non-commutative is not a Bad Thing. There's lots of ways to represent the orientation of a rigid body in 3-Space, but what what makes quaternions attractive is that if we have the quaternions representing a _sequence_ of rotations, we can multiply them together to get a single rotation that puts the object into the same, final orientation. Performing rotations in sequence is _not_ a commutative operation. Being "numbers like" might make the math easier, but being _reality like_ is what makes it actually useful.

Comment: Okay. General relativity uses tensors, for instance.

Answer (score 42):

Commutativity is over-rated: in fact, it holds back bicomplex numbers:

- It prevents your number system characterising non-commuting operations, e.g. rotations in $3$-dimensional space, Hamilton's original focus.
- Since $0=i^2-j^2=(i-j)(i+j)$ in bicomplex numbers, you have zero divisors, so it's not a normed division algebra; no convenient conjugates, no general definition of $a/b$ even with $b\ne0$, which hinders the description of invertible processes - again, such as rotations. (Apart from conjugation, these are also issues with "hyperbolic" or split-complex numbers, viz. $0=1-j^2=(1-j)(1+j)$.) In this respect, your number system runs into difficulties even octonions don't face, though sedenions do. I can't offer a comprehensive overview of how this has stymied historical use, but uses of split-complex numbers have never become widespread (even when they arguably deserved to be, e.g. [you can use split-complex numbers in relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/615119), but ironically complex numbers [have proved more popular](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155762/complex-numbers-in-quantum-mechanics-and-in-special-relativity) for this).

Comment: Split-complex numbers are totally good numbers system. Why it is not widespread? Because complex numbers are even better. But tessarines is a combination of the two. I cannot call a non-commutative system "numbers" at all.

Comment: @Anixx That's just a made-up rule. You might as well say complex numbers aren't numbers because you want numbers to be totally ordered. "Numbers" are whatever we need.

Comment: Well, absence of commutativity strikes away a lot of rewriting rules. Zero divisors don't.

Comment: @Anixx Do you mean because fewer rearrangements are legal? That never upset group theorists. For many applications, that division is undefined is much worse than some equations no longer being true.

Comment: Non-commutative vectors or matrices? Okay. But non-commutative numbers? No, they are not numbers any more, all our rules of working with numbers go away. Notice also that in 4-dimensional quaternion you add 2 more units to complex numbers. In tessarines you add just one, $j$, and you have 4 dimensions.

Comment: @Anixx, the most important attribute a mathematical system can have is that it is useful.  Things like "stylistic elegance" take a distant second place.

Comment: @Mark even useful things sometimes are not numbers.

Comment: @Anixx As far as I can tell, people don't call the quaternions numbers, generally. They call them quaternions, or the quaternion algebra (compare matrix and matrix algebra). I think that no occurrence of "number" in this answer refers to the quaternions, although the one in the first bullet point is debatable I suppose.

Comment: @Anixx Just to correct a factual error: quaternions also work by adding $j$ only, then defining $k:=ij$ purely as a shorthand. You can do the same with bicomplex numbers.

Comment: @benrg On the other hand, quaternions are considered "hypercomplex numbers".

Comment: @Anixx You asked an HSM historical question, why have bicomplex numbers been used less than quaternions? The meaning of the word "number" is irrelevant to that question. Mathematicians, physicists etc. use whichever mathematical objects they've found use for. My answer focused on the historical reasons invertible non-commutative objects (which, yes, have a matrix representation) were more helpful than non-invertible commutative objects (which, yes, have a matrix representation).

Comment: @benrg Quaternions, along with tessarines and many others, are traditionally called [hypercomplex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number).

Comment: All what you said is correct, but I would add that the [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) are actually quite useful, arguably, much more useful in, say, algebraic geometry, than the quaternions. The presence of nilpotents in the ring of dual numbers (and Artin local rings in greater generality) is a feature, not a bug.  (Just nitpicking.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan Dual numbers have their uses - I even linked to one - but zero divisors *are* a downside of the $4$-dimensional number system the bicomplex numbers comprise. As a rule, you use the smallest system that has what you need.

Comment: Well, may be zero devisors a downside (but we anyway cannot divide by ANY number or expression, even in reals), but having infinite number of solutions to an algebraic equation, like in quaternions, looks worse. In 4D tessarines a n-th order polynomial has no more than $n^2$ roots.

Comment: @Anixx Whatever your opinions on how many roots various equations deserve, I'll leave you to ponder why a normed division algebra might have proven historically more useful.

Answer (score 27):

Your description "total uselessness of quaternions" in a comment above is poorly chosen, and reflects more on your interests than on the real state of knowledge of mathematics. The Hamilton quaternions are the simplest nontrivial example of a *quaternion algebra*, which has turned out to be a really important concept in mathematics.

It is useful to think of the Hamilton quaternions $\mathbf H$ as being analogous to the ring of $2 \times 2$ real matrices ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf R)$. At first these might seem quite different: one is a division ring and the other is not. But here are analogies between them: both are 4-dimensional with center the real numbers and in both of them there is no 2-sided ideal other than $(0)$ and the whole ring. A ring that is 4-dimensional over a subfield $K$, has $K$ as its center, and has no 2-sided ideals other than $(0)$ and the whole ring is called a quaternion algebra over $K$.
The matrix ring ${\rm M}_2(K)$ is a quaternion algebra over $K$, and it is the only kind that is not a division ring.

Sometimes ${\rm M}_2(K)$ is the only quaternion algebra over $K$, e.g., when $K = \mathbf C$ and when $K$ is a finite field. There are two quaternion algebras over $\mathbf R$: ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf R)$ and $\mathbf H$. Similarly, there are two quaternion algebras over the $p$-adic numbers for each prime $p$. For $p = 2$ the two examples are ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf Q_2)$ and the Hamilton quaternions with $\mathbf Q_2$-coefficients, but for odd primes $p$ you need to do something different to get the "nontrivial" example because the Hamilton quaternions with $\mathbf Q_p$ coefficients is isomorphic to ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf Q_p)$ rather than being a division ring.

Things get really interesting for fields like $K = \mathbf Q$, because
there are *infinitely many* different quaternion algebras over $\mathbf Q$. The ring ${\rm M}_2(\mathbf Q)$ and the rational Hamilton quaternions are merely two examples out of a huge list of rational quaternion algebras. These "new" rational quaternion algebras show up in various places in mathematics: (supersingular) elliptic curves, Brauer groups, Shimura curves, and hyperbolic geometry in 2 and 3 dimensions.  Take a look at John Voight's [book](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ejvoight/quat-book.pdf) in order to appreciate that you should not dismiss quaternions as being a "totally useless" concept.  If you look at Ribet's [paper](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eribet/Articles/invent_100.pdf) that showed Fermat's Last Theorem is a consequence of modularity of elliptic curves over $\mathbf Q$, you'll see a role there for rational quaternion algebras that are division rings and are not the rational Hamilton quaternions.

Comment: The 2x2 real matrices are called split-quaternions and they unfortunately are not in the table in question. Still, they are both non-commutative and have zero-divisors, so not quite good at having numerical properties.

Answer (score 11):

Hamilton expected that the quaternions would be of physical interest. In this, he was right. But he was too early. He had discovered them in 1843, it was almost a century later, in 1928, when Dirac discovered his equation involving the Pauli matrices, that it was seen that the quaternions were naturally implicated in quantum field theory. (Here, the Pauli matrices are a representation of the quaternions on the space of 2 complex dimensional space).

Comment: Maxwell actually based his equations on quaterions. The whole vector calculus was in quaternions before Gibbs and Heaviside. There are other ways how to represent 3D rotations and Pauli matrices too (e.g. geometric algebra).

Comment: @Vladimir F: I'd forgotten that Maxwell had used quaternions. Coincidentally, I was just looking at geometric algebra - aka Clifford alfebras - before just coming onto the site now.

Comment: The quaternions may have helped inspire the algebra of Dirac gamma matrices, but the two are different. The crucial difference is that $\gamma^0$ anticommutes with all of $\gamma^1$ through $\gamma^3$, whereas in the quaternions $1$ commutes with all of $i$, $j$, and $k$. For the Pauli matrics, we are just back to 3D rotations.

Comment: @Lars H: Thanks for pointing this out. I'll edit my post when I find out a bit more. I think I should be thinking about Clifford algebras rather than quaternions here.